# Oracle APEX - Selecting next row to insert into using a process on form submit

Tags: sql, oracle, process, oracle-apex

Ok. I have a situation where I have two companies, COMPANY1 and COMPANY2, which work in tandem to create a PART. Since they worked together they both have ownership and therefore want to both assign a PART_NUMBER to the same part. COMPANY1 provides COMPANY2 a block of PART_NUMBERS to assign to the parts they create.

I have a table (TABLE_PARTS) which contains the primary key (COMPANY1_PART_NUMBER). Since COMPANY1 provided COMPANY2 with a block of numbers the table has been populated with just these numbers and awaits assignment to an actual part.

I have an input form that is to be used by COMPANY2 to plug in the part information, including the COMPANY2_PART_NUMBER. I need to updated the rows in TABLE_PARTS to fill out the rest of the columns around the pk, COMPANY1_PART_NUMBER, thus assigning that number to a part.

I have determined that I need to SELECT the MIN(COMPANY1_PART_NUMBER) where COMPANY2_PART_NUMBER is null and update that row with the part information.

I need to determine which row will be updated with a process after the form has been submitted because there will be concurrent users for the form and to select a row when the page loads would certainly cause people to accidentally attempt to insert into the same COMPANY1_PART_NUMBER row.

Any thoughts? I am sure it is not difficult but I am having issues, lol. Thanks!

Comment: Pfew, i'm trying to understand :) I need some clarification: does company 1 create parts? Do created parts end up in a table specific to company 1, or is this a 'shared' table like TABLE_PARTS? When you say that company 1 sends company 2 a block of numbers, what does this mean: do company 1 and 2 run on different databases/schemas/..., does company 2 have any idea of what these numbers are, or are the numbers just a range in which company 2 can assign parts 'local' to them? Take a look at this image http://imgur.com/bedo4, does this resemble anything at all?

Comment: It is a joint table like your example after 'OR'. The parts are created and manufactured by COMPANY2. COMPANY1 helped with the design and has some stake of ownership in COMPANY2 so they apply their own part numbers to COMPANY2's parts. So there is one part in TABLE_PARTS with a unique part number from both COMPANY1 and COMPANY2. COMPANY1 provides COMPANY2 with a block of numbers of some range which may be a simple incremental range or it may not. As such I cannot use a sequence just to increment the number.

Comment: The COMPANY1_PART_NUMBERs need to be either in this table or another and assigned to a part on submit. COMPANY1_PART_NUMBERs can be assigned to any COMPANY2_PART_NUMBER because COMPANY1_PART_NUMBERs have no attributes beyond just the PN. SO the COMPANY1_PART_NUMBERs need to be stored somewhere, whether in TABLE_PARTS or some other table and then they need to be assigned to a row when COMPANY2 submits a part. Make sense?

Comment: The built in update process requires the PK (COMPANY1_PART_NUMBER) to be in a field on the page which means I would have to assign it onpageload, but if someone loads the same page before the other user submits the form they would call the same COMPANY1_PART_NUMBER and then overwrite the previous user's row. However this ends up working the most important thing is that it reliably provides users from COMPANY2 with unique COMPANY1_PART_NUMBERs. When there are no more COMPANY1_PART_NUMBERs in the table it should return an error.

Comment: Ok, i think it's a lot more clear now (i hope x) ): there is a table with just parts in it, and holds a company2_part_number.  Company 2 gets sent a list with numbers from company 1, and assigns these numbers to the parts (it just simply takes a number from that list, there is no link to a specific part or anything, just a list of numbers). So, do you need the user to be able to see the number they will assign when they go into the form? (i wouldn't think they'd care at creation time since the number is 'random') I'd think it be the most important to have it shown after assignment.

Comment: For example, would it be good to just provide a checkbox or a button that creates the link? This'd be easy to have a process for. If you return the user to the same page after using this, they'd jsut as easily see the assigned number.  It'd also be the safest: there is no use showing the user a number before it is actually assigned, due to what you state: on submit it may not longer be valid. Suppose they already wrote down the number somewhere, presuming that nothing could go wrong - i'd find it annoying.

Comment: Ish, lol. There is an empty table TABLE_PARTS which starts off only containing COMPANY1_PART_NUMBERS. Then when a user from COMPANY2 comes along and fills out an input form, which captures COMPANY2_PART_NUMBER including all of the other part attributes, that data needs to be assigned to a row with a COMPANY1_PART_NUMBER but which is otherwise blank (i.e. I dont want to overwrite other parts). As you noted displaying COMPANY1_PART_NUMBER on the form is a terrible idea and I would like to avoid it. I will display all of the information together on a separate 'receipt' page after assignment.

Comment: All I care about is that I can reliably assign the unique stored COMPANY1_PART_NUMBERs to the submitted form data. If the C1_P_Ns need to be in a seperate table and then pulled into TABLE_PARTS on insert of the other data that works too. The users need no visibility of C1_P_N prior to its assignment to their data.

Comment: Ok, so it is when the user actually fills out the form, that you link it up with company 1? So when they press submit after they're ready with putting in the new details, all that needs to happen is assign a company1_part_number, and if that fails, an error is shown and the details remain 'unlinked'?

Comment: If there are no COMPANY1_PART_NUMBERS in the table then the submission should not go through. But yeah, basically what you just said. Basically I want to just SELECT MIN(COMPANY1_PART_NUMBER) FROM TABLE_PARTS WHERE COMPANY2_PART_NUMBER IS NULL and insert the form contents into that row... make sense?

Comment: Sorry I am so bad at explaining this, lol. Usually my questions do not cause so much confusion! If you can help me I would be VERY appreciative.

Answer (score 0):

So what you need is:

- one and only one user can have a certain free part id somewhere on the page. It is not allowed to have the user open the form and let them fill out details and then have the process fail after submitting the page due to for example, number already taken by another user.
- this already rules out the standard mechanisms used in apex. Concurrency and lost update checks only happen in the DML processing point, usually on submit after computations and validations.
- i was thinking about marking a row which a user selects for updating. However, this would also have to be undone. That is okay as long as a user actually clicks the Cancel button, but you can't catch other events without an extra framework. Even then, you can only catch browser events. If the user would shoot down the browser process or even crash, what will happen with the marked record!? It'll just sit there, waiting for a developer to fix this, or not realizing they never actually ran out of numbers.
- maybe it'd be possible to write an own locking mechanism: create a lock onload of the page. Name this lock after the chosen part id, so it can be checked against.  Another onload process on this page should check a lock on the input id. If a lock exists, then fail and do something, like a redirect. A created lock can also be given a timeout, so this would actually provide a backup for crashing browsers and computers. You'd then need to remove this lock when the user cancels the operation. Clicking away through breadcrumbs or navigation is still not caught, but you could rely on the lock timeout. Or use a framework extension such as the Skillbuilders save before exit. You could then use a page process to remove the lock on the different exit events (through ajax calls). The solution would still not be 100% optimal though. An example would be where there is only 1 record left, and a user wants to assign something. However, a lock is still timing out for some reason, so the user gets an error message and so is led to believe no ids are left. Again, this may be solved by providing a more detailed error message, stating there are numbers left but are currently locked ("*try again later*"? - :-/ )

These things just play in my head atm. I've been trying some things like 'select for update nowait', but it doesn't work. Probably because as soon as the block has been runned, the lock is released.

I was hoping i'd find something through google, but no joy really. I haven't run into this requirement myself (yet?), so i'm also a bit stumped on how this could best be solved.

Edit: i remember i've used dbms_locks somewhere in the last 5 years, and maybe you should try it out. DBMS_LOCK can't be used on apex.oracle.com however, and i don't have rights to it in my db at work (and dba isn't here). So go ahead and take a look at [DBMS_LOCK](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_lock.htm), and at [this example](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/plsql/sync_sessions.html).

What you'd do is: create an onload-after headers process, and create an exclusive lock there (exclusive, you don't want to share anything of course). You'd want this id to be unique to the part id selected. Make sure to have either an timeout on the lock (default is MAXWAIT = forever!) or have a process on cancelling to release the lock, so you won't run in trouble testing it out.

```
-- this is just a handle though, not the actual lock
dbms_lock.allocate_unique(lockname        => 'lock_part_'||company1_part_id,
                          lockhandle      => v_lockhandle, 
                          expiration_secs => 300 -- 5 mins
                         ); 

-- request does the actual lock,
-- so this'll give errors when called for the same lockhandle 
-- and a lock is already in effect
v_result := dbms_lock.request(lockhandle => v_lockhandle, 
                              lockmode => dbms_lock.x_mode, 
                              timeout => 0 -- fail instantly and don't wait to put a lock if already locked,
                              release_on_commit => true/false -- try both, not sure if it'll work with TRUE
                             );
```

> release_on_commit
>   Set this parameter to TRUE to release the lock on
>   commit or roll-back.
>
> Otherwise, the lock is held until it is explicitly released or until
>   the end of the session.

If things are good, another session won't be able to lock the same id then due to the lock you've created. Error catching you'll have to try yourself, but it shouldn't be to hard testing for the existing lock and providing adequate feedback for the errors.

> DBMS_LOCK.request
>   Return Values
>
> Table 70-10 REQUEST Function Return Values
>
> Return Value Description
>   0  Success
>   1  Timeout
>   2  Deadlock
>   3  Parameter error
>   4  Already own lock specified by id or lockhandle
>   5  Illegal lock handle

I like extending apex, but if you'd have to go out of your way this much for just one page, and have many different processes, all custom to this one page... Maybe there IS an easy way, i just can't see it myself aswell (yet).

Comment: Yeah, I do not want them to be able to pick out a COMPANY1_PART_NUMBER... What prevents two users from both clicking 'Assign Parts' and getting the same COMPANY1_PART_NUMBER? How is this different than simply calling the value into a txtbox using a SQL string on page load?

Comment: Yeah I just tried opening the app in two windows and clicked 'Assign Parts' in each and both loaded with the same COMPANY1_PART_NUMBER. It only allows one to properly submit but it shows the number to both. What if we used to tables? One to store the COMPANY1_PART_NUMBERs and another to serve as TABLE_PARTS. On insert could we use a process or trigger to pull the next COMPANY1_PART_NUMBER from its table and put it with the data in TABLE_PARTS?

Comment: Yeah, that would've been my first thought too, but i believed you already had this system - so i tried that. About the same number: yeah, you're right, onload process would do the same, and yes, 2 users can be working the same part. I was trying to keep it simple :) I'm not sure how to make sure there is only one user using a specific part though. I suppose you could use an extra field in the part table you fill out with an 'X' or so, but then you'd need to blank it out again in several places, and leaving a page doesn't trigger anything (unless you want to use javascript)

Comment: tbh, i'd still allow different users having the same part selected, having it fail on submit. You could then preload another part number. Maybe not optimal, but i'd consider it

Comment: Well let's step away from overly simple for a minute then... because honestly this doesn't meet my needs. Let's look st the solution we both mentioned in the last comment, the one you said was your first thought. Thanks!

Comment: I've edited my answer. No solution yet, just writing down what i'm thinking of in hopes of finding a suitable solution. I'll pick this up again as soon as i can. But tbh, it seemed easier than it actually is, i never thought for this to be so 'difficult'.

Comment: Yeah, I NEVER thought that this would be such a pain. I figured it was just something simple I was missing. I tried the DBMS_LOCK option and I do not believe that it is turned on on my DB either. Unfortunately my DBA is in coorporate IT and the chances of them every bothering to activate something even IF it got approved to do so is unlikely. I am pretty much stuck with whatever settings they have on at the moment.

Comment: Lets take a step back for a moment. Would it be possible to do your first solution but NOT display the COMPANY1_PART_NUMBER on the page? I can deal with the form failing for now, to get SOMETHING functioning, as long as I havent already shown that user a PN. Typically APEX does not like to deal with passing data from hidden or disabled fields. Do you know a way around that?

Comment: By first solution, do you mean like what i had in my OTN workspace? If so, totally, probably leaving the field hidden would work. Apex shouldn't have trouble dealing with hidden items, but disabled items would not work, since those are not posted to the server (which is standard html form behaviour)

Comment: Yeah the demo you made and posted. Hmm... you are right. The hidden field does work. I could have sworn that it didn't before. How were you dealing with multiple updates before? I cannot seem to get mine to throw an error, it simply overwrites the previous update. You mentioned you could possibly give me some credentials or something for that workspace to play with that example? That way I could look at what you have in the backend and not have to bother you so much.

Comment: http://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=54687:13 takes you there. You can leave out pg13, you can do most from pg14. To login as dev: workspace: tompetrusbe, apex_demo/demo. pages 13-14-16-17. I "prevent" multiple updates by actually having a row selected from the table, so the builtin mechanism does the lost update checking.